# Is lighting different from Immediate mode rendering to VBOs?

Tags: shaders, lighting, vbo, jogl

I recently got a textured cube to render as a VBO, and I've noticed some strange things as I have been trying to incorporate lighting.

Firstly, there is no difference if I comment out any lines involving the shaders. Does that mean I am using the default shaders? Do I need custom shaders for lighting to work correctly?

Second, the VBO cube has the same ambient lighting as the immediate mode cubes, but the VBO cube does not have the diffuse lighting. I've changed the color of the ambient lighting to blue to make this more obvious. There is one VBO cube next to two adjacent immediate mode cubes.

This is the front, with the light pointing at the cubes: [image: front of cubes]

This is the back, when the other cubes have ambient lighting too: [image: back of cubes]

So, with ambient light working, I am thinking it is possible to get diffuse too, is that true? Or, do I need to get the shaders working and implement lighting there?

For lighting, I set everything up by saying:

```
    // Enable lighting in GL.
    gl.glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    gl.glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);

    gl.glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); // enables depth testing
    gl.glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL); // the type of depth test to do
    gl.glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST); // best
                                                            // perspective
                                                            // correction

    gl.glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH); // blends colors nicely, and smoothes out
                                // lighting

    // Add colors to texture maps, so that glColor3f(r,g,b) takes effect.
    gl.glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    gl.glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE);
    gl.glEnable(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

And for each frame I also say:

```
    gl.glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, lightColorAmbient, 0);
    gl.glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, lightDif, 0);
    gl.glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, lightColorSpecular, 0);
    gl.glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lightPos, 0);
```

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't use normals (bind them, set them, etc) on my VBO, but they were already on my immediate mode cubes.